# QgsLegend link error when building

Tags: qgis, legend, error

I'm developing a software using QGIS. When building my software there is a LINK error.

```
1>mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "public: __thiscall 
   QgsLegend::QgsLegend(class QgsMapCanvas *,class QWidget *,char const 
   *)"(??0QgsLegend@@QAE@PAVQgsMapCanvas@@PAVQWidget@@PBD@Z) référencé dans la 
   fonction "public: __thiscall MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *,class 
   QFlags<enum Qt::WindowType>)" 
(??0MainWindow@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@V?$QFlags@W4WindowType@Qt@@@@@Z)
1>C:\Documents and Settings\XXXXX\mes documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\XXXXX
\XXXXXX.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 externes non résolus
```

I'm using QGIS 1.7.2, QT 4.7.3, Visual Studio 2010 (with VC10), and there were no errors when I built the sources of QGIS.
I've already put all the .libs I found in the link editor of VS10.
In QGIS API, it is written that for the `QgsLegend`, I had to link the `qgis_gui.lib`, so had I.

I don't know what I can do now. Can someone help me ?  Or how to proceed in order to find the lib i missed.

If you need more information, just ask. I'm really blocked...

Answer (score 2):

QgsLegend isn't part of the API.  You can't use it in applications.  Plugins can access it via [QgsLegendInterface](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsLegendInterface.html).